# Deploy error in Webistrano with bundler, capistrano and require 'bundler/capistrano' recipe

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano, bundler, webistrano

Recently I've been trying to upgrade Webistrano from a version that did not use bundler to manage the application gems to one that does.  In order to deploy rails applications, we would use `require 'bundler/capistrano'` in the recipe to have the bundler loaded for the application and other related steps (like precompiling assets, etc.).  However, once bundler is used with a Gemfile to specify and load the appropriate gem environment, having `require 'bundler/capistrano'` throws the following error:

> ** loading stage recipe 'bundler'
>
> *** defining a task named `install' would shadow an existing method with that name

If I exclude the require from the recipe, the deploy continues but does not use bundler (no `bundle exec`, etc.)

I also have similar issues with `require 'rvm/capistrano'` when attempting to use `rvm` to manage the ruby environment.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you are using rake 0.9.x which has install task
https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/contrib/sys.rb#L30
try to run with rake 0.8.7
This issue might be related https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/90

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the bundler and rvm-capistrano gems installed on your server and local machine? I've seen this causing issues before.

Comment: No, should I?  I have bundler on the deploy host machines.  rvm-capistrano on the deploy server.

Comment: I've seen people having problems with not having those locally too.

Answer (score 0):

I had just checked the code of `bundler/capistrano` and I know code of `rvm/capistrano`, the only way that could make that happen is when `capistrano`'s `namespace` is overwritten/broken and does not give a proper scope to `task` definitions, make sure you do not redefine `namespace` or there is no other `gem`/`library`/`code` that would do that.

Possibly updating capistrano to newer version could just fix it (that could be some already fixed bug in `capistrano`).